# didSelectRowAtIndexPath resizes the imageview on iOS7

Tags: ios7, uitableview

This happens if cell.selectionStyle is different than UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.

```
        //FrameFiew

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    ...
         imageView = [[FXImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
                            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                            imageView.asynchronous = YES;
                            imageView.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
                            imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
                      //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    ...
    }
```

[image]

Comment: how tall is your table view cell?  at least 50 pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on FXImageView framework, I just change to UIImageView and now it works.

Comment: Correct. IOS 7.1 made some internal changes to UIImageView that broke how I was handling image cropping. The new version creates its own backing layer, so should be robust against further changes.

Comment: I was using Version 1.3.3, so it will be on a future release? thx

Comment: No, the fix was included in 1.3.3. I think the issue is unrelated.

Comment: So please, check it again. Thx

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. If you have a project where you can reproduce the bug, can you open an issue on the github page? Thanks.